# How would I write this simple Bash variable-based method?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

The goal is to make a method that would grep and `git checkout` to the branch search.

```
    function gf { 
        result=$(git branch -l | grep "$1");
        git checkout $result;
    }
    export -f gf
```

So that one could do..

```
gf 150_
```

And I would immediately be on the branch of choice.

Unfortuantely, my method does not work.

Comment: The $1 should be in double quotes. Also double quote the variable result.

Comment: yup, with double quotes "$1" it should work

Comment: @Inian Hmm.. I added the double quote, but it doesn't seem to actually `git checkout`

Comment: @Inian I tried with double quotes and it doesn't git checkout either.